# How to use a hyphen in cookie names for nginx?

Tags: nginx, cookie, http-cookie

I want to use the new [cookie-prefixes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-prefixes-00), which are not yet standardized by the IETF. These are `__Secure-` and `__Host-`.

So let's e.g. set this cookie (here the header returned by the server):

```
Set-Cookie: "__Host-apple=yummy; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/"
```

I want to access this cookie now in nginx with the `$cookie-` variable. So for testing I use the echo module to show me the value of the cookie:

```
location = /wannaeat/ {
        echo $cookie___Host-apple;
}
```

However nginx always shows me `-apple`. It seems to use the hyphen (`-`) to split the variable.

Because when I e.g. name the cookie `__Host_apple` (and the nginx variable `$cookie___Host_apple`) nginx shows me the value correctly.

I know I could probably use `$http_cookie` and use a regular expression to find the correct cookie, but this is not possible as I want to [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) the cookie value.

Comment: Currently cookie with dash could not be accessed via `$cookie_...` variable. You could extract it from `$http_cookie` variable (e.g. http://www.ur-ban.com/2012/03/18/logging-nginx-cookies-with-dashes/) or access it from Lua script (if your nginx built with Lua support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [`map`](http://nginx.org/r/map) does, in fact, support matching on regular expressions:

> Source values are specified as strings or regular expressions (0.9.6).

(Thus you should probably be good to go!)

---

However, for the sake of discussion and commentary, since what you're attempting to use is not a standard yet, you better go to their mailing lists or whatnot, and tell them that what they're proposing to do is a really bad idea.

Just for the sake of it, I went to the Cookie Manager in my browser, to make a look at the use of `_` the underscore versus `-` the shortest dash.  The underscore is heavily used by at least 90% of sites/cookies, whereas dash usage within cookies is probably way below 5%.

The reason why `-` is not valid in variable names is very straightforward and is as old as day -- because the symbol is often used in pretty much all programming languages in place of the minus sign (dash, minus, mdash: -−—).  In turn, as per [`re_format(7)`](http://mdoc.su/f/re_format.7) and [`pcrepattern(3)`](http://mdoc.su/n/pcrepattern.3), this scenario is also part of the widely used regular expression implementations, where an underscore is always considered to be a part of a word, whereas a dash symbol is not.

I'd imagine the same issue will repeat itself in many other languages as well as with nginx.conf.

Comment: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2016JulSep/0015.html

Comment: Hyphens in cookies are not entirely unheard of; e.g. https://gist.github.com/abersager/2244435

Comment: @cnst Thanks for commenting there. You could also have linked to this question as a practical example for a server software (& a stupid server admin ;) ), where one can encounter (/who has encountered) this issue.

Comment: @rugk, someone already did that in a reply; i, personally, like to avoid linking to SO, because it promotes monoculture.  thanks for accept and presumably an upvote! :-)